# using the mongodb entry while updating

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongdb structure which looks like this:

```
{'_id':1, 'aggregate_sum': 12, 'total':10, 'mean':1.2}
```

I want to update this database's mean.

```
num =12
value = db.find_one({'_id':1})
new_mean = (value['mean']*value['total'] + num )/(value['total']+1)
db.update({'_id':1, {'$inc':{'aggregate_sum':num, 'total':1},{"$set" :{'mean':new_mean})
```

Can I prevent the first call to mongo and instead update the mean on fly. I am thinking of some reference to the current mongodb object being processed like `this` in `javascript`?

Comment: Don't know the Python driver, but maybe [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) is what you are looking for – [which can be used in pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify). However, the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) might be suited, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presently cannot reference another field within an update (yet). You could try iterating through the documents and update each document then call the save method:

```
num = 12
for value in db.find({'_id': 1}):
    new_mean = (value['mean']*value['total'] + num )/(value['total'] + 1)
    value['aggregate_sum'] += num
    value['total'] += 1
    value['mean'] = new_mean
    db.save(value)
```